# WPF root element is not valid for navigation

Tags: wpf

I am converting a WPF XBAP app to a WPF desktop app.  I have it running on the desktop, but am now trying to change the Page references to Window references.

```
'MyApp.StartForm' root element is not valid for navigation.
```

I have tried creating a simple version of this app and converting that, and this works fine, so there must be something within the XAML that is causing this when using Window tags.  My question relates to how I can investigate this.  Currently, all I get is this error, accompanied by a "No Source Available" screen; no stack locations are shown and "Show Disassembly" doesn't work.  Other than systematically commenting out individual chunks of XAML until it works, is there a way to work out what this issue is?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Navigation in a WPF application can only be done between pages.  The error shows up because you're trying to "navigate" to what is now a Window, and this isn't possible.

Instead of converting your Page into a Window, create a new Window with a `Frame` control in it.  A `Frame` can be used to host your existing pages - which should stay exactly as they are, and not be changed into Windows.

Answer (score 7):

Its not entirely accurate about it not being possible to host a window in a frame, the following code will do it for you

```
    public void HostWindowInFrame(Frame fraContainer, Window win) {
        object tmp = win.Content;
        win.Content = null;
        fraContainer.Content = new ContentControl() { Content = tmp };
    }
```

Comment: This doesn't host the window, but the window's content instead. It may be valid in some cases, but not if you still need the window's frame or if you're dealing with airspace issues.

Answer (score 0):

please check StartForm having the page as root element or some other else. I am having the same. I have check the page which has to be navigated. I declare that page as window.