# Navigation between pages in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, window

I have my WPF application and my button is on a WINDOW that I added and I want the button to open a PAGE when I click it.

```
NavigationService nav = NavigationService.GetNavigationService(this); 
nav.Navigate(new Uri("xamlFeedbackPage.xaml", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute));
```

I have tried that code that was online and my application crashes when I click the button.

Any help?

Comment: Is the "xamlFeedbackPage.xaml" located in the root of your project? Else you might have to change it into something like "/Pages/xamlFeedbackPage.xaml". And just try to set UriKind to Absolute.

Comment: @YoupTube http://i.stack.imgur.com/i2R5G.png Yes as you can see from picture its it the root folder with all other pages/windows.

Comment: I see and changing the UriKind to absolute?

Comment: Is there a valid (non-null) reference to the navigation service?

Comment: @YoupTube Still crashes ....

Comment: @YoupTube Yes there is 

using System.Windows.Navigation;

Comment: I think what @YoupTube means is for you to make sure that `nav` is not null.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7078052/wpf-root-element-is-not-valid-for-navigation) and this [MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.navigation.navigationservice.getnavigationservice%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). They contain explanation about what kind of Types are suitable for navigation (pages) and in which container to host them (basically a Frame). Then you should have some succes.

EDIT

Take a look at [this extensive example](http://paulstovell.com/blog/wpf-navigation) and things will become clear.

Comment: Hey had a look at them articles and ill try and follow them though i think it is because you can only navigate from PAGE to PAGE where i am trying to go from a window to a page.

Comment: I have created a new Window called HostInWindowFrame.xaml and added a frame but i dont understand the way it works?

Comment: Then you set Frame.Content to a specific page (with a button on it) and when you push the button you call the code you originally posted.

Answer (score 0):

```
    public PageFunction1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        NavigationService nav = NavigationService.GetNavigationService(this);
        nav.Navigate(new Uri("page2.xaml",UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute));
    }
```

Comment: you just use page not use window or u may use navigate window.. did u getting me?

Comment: Please add description to your answer

Answer (score 0):

No need of call anything in the code.Since it can be done with xaml itself.

App.xaml

```xml
        <Application x:Class="WpfApplication1.App"
                     xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                     xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                     StartupUri="Page1.xaml">
        </Application>
```

Page1

```xml
        <Page x:Class="WpfApplication1.Page1"
              xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
              xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
              Title="Page1">
            <StackPanel>
                <TextBlock>
                    Go to <Hyperlink NavigateUri="Page2.xaml"> Page 2 </Hyperlink>
                </TextBlock>
            </StackPanel>
        </Page>
```

[Navigate sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UWCNe.png)

Page 2

```xml
        <Page x:Class="WpfApplication1.Page2"
              xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
              xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
              Title="Page2"> 
            <StackPanel>
                <TextBlock Margin="10">Welcome to Page2.</TextBlock>
                <TextBlock Margin="10">
                    Go back to <Hyperlink NavigateUri="Page1.xaml"> Page 1 </Hyperlink>
                </TextBlock>
            </StackPanel>
        </Page>
```

Comment: I don't think hardcoding navigation values in the xaml is the optimal solution.